# Does not update the field using trigger

Tags: trigger

I need to update the value of the lookup field upon lead conversion. This is the code

```
trigger mapFieldsLookup on Contact (before insert) {

    set<String> status_text = new set<String>();
    set<String> org_text = new set<String>();
    set<String> payclass_text = new set<String>();
    set<String> position_text = new set<String>();
    set<String> taxcode_text = new set<String>();

    for(Contact cont : Trigger.new)
    {
         If(String.isNotBlank(cont.Employment_Status_Text__c) ||
             String.isNotBlank(cont.Organization_Unit_Text__c)||
             String.isNotBlank(cont.Pay_Classfication_Text__c)||
             String.isNotBlank(cont.Position_text__c)         ||
             String.isNotBlank(cont.Tax_Code_Text__c)) {

            status_text.add(cont.Employment_Status_Text__c);
            org_text.add(cont.Organization_Unit_Text__c);
            payclass_text.add(cont.Pay_Classfication_Text__c);
            position_text.add(cont.Position_text__c);
            taxcode_text.add(cont.Tax_Code_Text__c);
            }           
    }
    map<String, Employee_Status_Reference_Record__c> mapStatus = new map<String, Employee_Status_Reference_Record__c>();
    map<String, Company_Organization_Record__c> mapOrg = new map<String, Company_Organization_Record__c>();
    map<String, Employee_Class_Reference_Record__c> mapPayclass = new map<String, Employee_Class_Reference_Record__c>();
    map<String, Position_Reference_Record__c> mapPosition = new map<String, Position_Reference_Record__c>();
    map<String, TAX_Reference_Record__c> mapTax = new map<String, TAX_Reference_Record__c>();

    for(Employee_Status_Reference_Record__c statusRef: [SELECT Id, Status_Code__c 
                                                                FROM Employee_Status_Reference_Record__c 
                                                               WHERE Status_Code__c IN: status_text]) 
    {
        mapStatus.put(statusRef.Status_Code__c, statusRef);
    }

    for(Company_Organization_Record__c orgRef: [SELECT Id,Organization_Code__c 
                                             FROM Company_Organization_Record__c
                                            WHERE Organization_Code__c IN: org_text])
    {

    mapOrg.put(orgRef.Organization_Code__c, orgRef);                        
    }

    for(Contact cont : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(mapStatus.containsKey(cont.Employment_Status_Text__c))
        {
            cont.Employment_Status__c = mapStatus.get(cont.Employment_Status_Text__c).Id; 
        }
        if(mapOrg.containsKey(cont.Employment_Status_Text__c))
        {
            cont.Organization_Unit__c  = mapOrg.get(cont.Organization_Unit_Text__c).Id; 
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesnt update the field, no errors either.

Comment: looks like you need to use before update instead and after update.. Also you are SOQL inside for loop..

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your trigger check below and also read all comment so you can understand the process.

```
trigger mapFieldsLookup on Contact (before insert) {

    set<String> setEmployment_Status_Text = new set<String>();
    for(Contact cont : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(String.isNotBlank(cont.Employment_Status_Text__c))
        {
            //add all status text in set for next query
            setEmployment_Status_Text.add(cont.Employment_Status_Text__c);
        }           
    }
    map<String, Employee_Status_Reference_Record__c> mapStatusTextTOEmpStatusRef = new map<String, Employee_Status_Reference_Record__c>();

    // query on Employee_Status_Reference_Record__c based on set that contains status text
    for(Employee_Status_Reference_Record__c objEmpStatusRef: [SELECT Id, Status_Code__c 
                                                                FROM Employee_Status_Reference_Record__c 
                                                               WHERE Status_Code__c IN: setEmployment_Status_Text])
    {
        mapStatusTextTOEmpStatusRef.put(objEmpStatusRef.Status_Code__c, objEmpStatusRef);
    }
    //iterate over trigger.new and check in map if status text present or not.
    //if present get the Employee_Status_Reference_Record__c based on status text.
    // and assign the Id to Employment_Status__c
    for(Contact cont : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(mapStatusTextTOEmpStatusRef.containsKey(cont.Employment_Status_Text__c))
        {
            cont.Employment_Status__c = mapStatusTextTOEmpStatusRef.get(cont.Employment_Status_Text__c).Id; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @gelay if this ans solved your issue. the pls accept the ans and upvote. :)

Comment: please see updated question